# How to highlight patterns in the text of a question?

Tags: support, questions, syntax-highlighting

I just edited [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern) where the description says something like <sub><sup>(not quoting to show the difference properly)</sup></sub>:

*If I want to find all the instances of, say, "th" in a number of files you do:*

I thought that "th" is a bit difficult to distinguish, so maybe using the backticks would improve the readability:

*If I want to find all the instances of, say, `th` in a number of files you do:*

But then I stopped and wondered: do we have any kind of standard way to approach this? What should be backticked and what should be double quoted? To me, backticking the word used in a regular expression or shell command adds precision, but I might be wrong.

I have done some research and did not find it, maybe I just did not find enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when the line is talking about variables (/names), function names, and of course, code snippets, I backtick them:

> So, `someFunc` accepts a couple of parameters, a `firstParameter` string, like `"foo"`, a boolean: `true`, and a number: `1.234`.
>   You can then call the function like this: `someFunc("foo", true, 1.234);`

Basically, I only use it as markup for pieces of code. In this case, the `"th"` could be considered a piece of code.

Please note that this is just my personal preference.

Comment: So you backtick and double quote it: `"foo"`. Interesting and even more readable...

Comment: Exactly. That way, it gets highlighted as code, while it's clear it's a string.

Comment: This is the best approach I've seen. And do you know if there is some kind of "standard" way of doing this?

Comment: There is no standard as far as I'm aware. Just do what (mostly) everyone else does, it seems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will use this approach from now on.

Comment: @fedorqui: consider 'I want to find "foo" in..' versus 'I want to find `foo` in ..' and 'I want to find `"foo"` in ..'.

Comment: @Jongware Yes! The problem may arise if the pattern to check contains a double quote. Say somebody is looking for the text `"hello` in a file. But this is an edge case which would be solved by just using backticks.